# Move to another url

Tags: jquery, url, back-button

I inherited some code which moves to another page, where page is a url.
      $('body').html(page);
it works but there is no way to use IE back button to move back to the previous page.

I'm looking for better ways move to another url but preserve all the pages in the IE back button.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript function

```
window.location.replace()
```

Comment: it moves to the page, but the previous sites in the Back Button don't exists. so I can't move to the previous page.

Comment: did you try this function . it should give you back button function ?

Comment: i tries your suggestion, but no back button

Comment: function MoveToURL (url){ window.location.replace(url);}

Comment: this works with back button function MoveToURL (url){ window.location(url);}

Answer (score 1):

you can use window.location.href to send your page to another, and use javascript:history.go(-1) to go back in your browser